# Try catch isn't catching Exception, Notimplemented, or notsupported exceptions

Tags: vb.net, exception

I currently am having trouble troubleshooting this line of code. I want to catch the exception, but it keeps running. Therefore, it's obviously an exception that isn't within System. I tried these other system exceptions (and random ones just to see) but once I hit F10, it instead keeps going in the code and not the next line! Obviously something is wrong but I can't catch it.

Any ideas?

Here's the code:

```
Try
    Dim txtRecord As New Bonjour.TXTRecord
    m_async = m_socket.BeginReceive(m_buffer, 0, m_buffer.Length, SocketFlags.Partial, New AsyncCallback(AddressOf OnReceive), Me)
    m_registrar = m_service.Register(0, 0, Environment.UserName, "_axis-video._tcp", "local", vbNullString, m_port, txtRecord, MyEventManager)
Catch ex As Exception

End Try
```

I'm using Bonjour in vb.net to try and use a mDNS service. Despite having breakpoints, the "catch" is never reached, and instead the window pops up with out any of these following services or code lines called.

**EDIT:** After taking after the very helpful comments (mentioned below!), I was able to catch it by calling the function by a non-load function. When that happened the expection was caught (socket exception).

Comment: Please don't add language tags (c#) if your code does not involve the language.

Comment: do you have a break-point set in the callback OnReceive?

Comment: Whoops, sorry about the C#. No I don't, and I'll try that break point.

Comment: Did you have this code in a win7 64bit under a Form.Load event and running inside VS? See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4933958/vs2010-does-not-show-unhandled-exception-message-in-a-winforms-application-on-a

Comment: where is this code located?

Comment: I don't have it under a load event, I actually have it (with same behavior) in a public function and in a New() instance of the class. I did it differently to see what would happen

Comment: but if that function is called from Form Load or the form's constructor the same thing happens.  we have no context.  you also did not answer Steve regarding Win 64bit

Comment: Ah, the original call is from a form load event. That might be it.

Comment: I have some dlls that are platform specific. Is there another way to fix besides changing the compile version's target cpu?

Comment: I have tried changing the target CPU to any, adding the unhandled exception in the load event, and nothing catches it.